# I updated to jdk 11 and now my code is throwing errors, and I can't figure out why, it all looks correct to me

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code, java-11

I just updated to jdk 11 on vscode and it's throwing errors I've never seen before. I really am pretty sure my code is correct, but it's talking about misplaced constructors and stuff, and I just don't get it.
[image: My code throwing errors]

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Huffman() {
    public Node BuildHuffmanCodeTree(String[] chars, int[] weights) {
        for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            Node tempNode = new Node(chars[i], weights[i]);
             
        }
    }    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    }
}
```

Here's the code for Node, in case that might be causing it. Node and Huffman are both located within the same folder, so Huffman should be able to see Node, right?

```
import java.util.Comparator;
public class Node{
    Node child1;
    Node child2;
    Boolean isLeaf;
    int weight;
    String letter;

    public Node(Node node1, Node node2) {
        this.child1 = node1;
        this.child2 = node2;
        this.weight = node1.getWeight() + node2.getWeight();
        this.letter = null;
        this.isLeaf = false;
    }

    public Node(Node node1) {
        this.child1 = node1;
        this.child2 = null;
        this.isLeaf = false;
        this.weight = node1.getWeight();
    }
    public Node(String character, int num) {
        this.child1 = null;
        this.child2 = null;
        this.isLeaf = true; 
        this.weight = num;
        this.letter = character;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return this.weight;
    }

    public String getChar() {
        return this.letter;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: First, you should try it on the command line using the JDK CLI tools. Compile your code and run your program on the command line. What happens? You should get at least some kind of error from your compiler or runtime.

Comment: "it's talking about misplaced constructors and stuff" - when talking about errors (exceptions, compile-time errors etc) please post the *precise error messages* (copy/paste them) rather than this sort of hand-waving.

Comment: But your (unconventinally-named) `BuildHuffmanCodeTree` method is definitely broken - you're not returning anything from it. And `public class Huffman()` shouldn't have the `()`. So no, your code is not correct. Always assume the compiler is right first - it's always more likely that the mistake is in your code than in the compiler.

Comment: May i know if you ever reached my answer? Kindly let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

Class Name don't need `()` when you define it as `public class Name` and your method `public Node BuildHuffmanCodeTree(String[] chars, int[] weights)` is not type of `void` so it needs **return** sentence. Changing `Huffman.java` to the following should be no errors:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Huffman {
    public Node BuildHuffmanCodeTree(String[] chars, int[] weights) {
        for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            Node tempNode = new Node(chars[i], weights[i]);
             
        }
        return null; //Not clear about your wanted function, but return sentence is needed here
    }    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    }
}
```